# Get list of files to recently pushed to remote Git branch

Tags: git, tortoisegit

How do I get a list of files that have been recently pushed to a remote branch using Git? Or is there any way to list out remote branch files?

I googled, but I do not get suggestion.

Comment: did you try git whatchanged remote/[branchname]? assuming of course - your remote is updated

Comment: No. I didnt try it. I will try it now.

Comment: @mustard, It is listing out mine and others files( which i have not pushed to the remote).

Comment: Git *is not capitalized* as "GIT", it's not an abbreviation like TFS, SVN, or CVS.

Comment: Git doesn't track pushes.  If the remote has reflogs turned on you can look there.

Answer (score 1):

**The following are strictly command-line solutions that don't use the TortoiseGit GUI client.**

To see what files have been pushed to a remote branch, just fetch the latest changes from the remote, then use `git log --name-status` or `git diff` to get a list of files that have been changed/added/deleted since you last fetched changes from the remote.

#### Using `git diff`

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git diff origin/master@{1} origin/master --name-status
A       hello.txt
```

Note that using `diff` with the reflog syntax `<branch>@{n}` here will only work if there are more than 1 entry for the branch in the reflog. Otherwise, you'll get this error:

```
$ git diff origin/master@{1} origin/master --name-status
fatal: Log for 'origin/master' only has 1 entries.
```

#### Using `git log`

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --name-status origin/master@{1}..origin/master
* 6e6ce69 Add hello.txt
  A     hello.txt
```

Again, using the reflog syntax `<branch>@{n}` will only work if there are more than 1 entry for the branch in the reflog. If you don't mind seeing the entire history for the branch, then you can just use this instead:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --name-status
* 952e133 Add Bash alias for `pbcopy` (OS X)
| M     osx/.bash_profile
* c843ea2 Set Vim column limit to 80 (OS X)
| M     osx/.vimrc
* 320ed55 Add "Base16 Dark Tomorrow" Sublime Text theme (OS X)
| M     editors/sublime-text/Preferences.sublime-settings
* ffff5a5 Add Bash configuration for Scala
| M     osx/.bash_profile
* 1b7f496 Add alias for Dr Java to Bash config (OS X)
| M     osx/.bash_profile
* 475593a Add global .gitignore file for OS X
| M     osx/.gitconfig
| A     osx/.global-gitignore
* 7668f34 Modify Bash config to use Homebrew recommended PATH
| M     osx/.bash_profile
```