# git diff origin/master@{1} origin/master --name-status throws fatal: Log for 'origin/master' only has 1 entries error

Tags: git, github

I am using git diff origin/master@{1} origin/master --name-status
command to print the previous push details.

But it is throwing fatal: Log for 'origin/master' only has 1 entries error.

I got to know that diff with the reflog syntax @{n} here will only work if there are more than 1 entry for the branch in the reflog.
from the answer

[Get list of files to recently pushed to remote Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932860/get-list-of-files-to-recently-pushed-to-remote-git-branch)

if i run this command in local it will work.But i have a CI/CD server which clones this repo and executes this.There am getting this reflog entry error.

Is there any way to restore atleast last two three entries in remote repo?

otherwise i need to execute the equivalent of it diff origin/master@{1} origin/master --name-status in a cloned repository

Comment: git reflog exists origin/master does not show any output ,but git reflog origin/master shows number of entries

Comment: To know where you have been you must not throw away the record of where you have been. But when you clone every time, you do just that. Don't do it. Reuse your repo.

Comment: When you clone a repo you pull the the current value of all refs. So, the initial value of all the refs is the current value. The syntax `@{1}` is asking for "the previous version" of a reference. In the current repo, there is no previous version of the ref - it is still at its initial value (which is the latest, most up-to-date value).

Comment: @j6t This isn't on a "normal" machine, it's on a CI/CD server. When I've set these up before, the approach has been "start everything from scratch" - so I'm not surprised to see that it's doing a clone.